# Order array by calculated field in javascript or php?

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

I have a js function that I have working to display a list of categories with the quiz results.  However the quiz results are calculated in the javascript and the php table I created just calls the initial array without the result.  That means I can order by anything in the array but I would like to order by the quiz %.  Should I be doing this in the js or php?

```
setCategoryOverview: function() {
                    results.comp.cats = {};

                    $e.find('.wpProQuiz_catOverview li').each(function() {
                        var $this = $(this);
                        var catId = $this.data('category_id');

                        if(config.catPoints[catId] === undefined) {
                            $this.hide();
                            return true;
                        }

                        var r = Math.round(catResults[catId] / config.catPoints[catId] * 100 * 100) / 100;

                        results.comp.cats[catId] = r;

                        $this.find('.wpProQuiz_catPercent').text(r + '%');

                        $this.show();
                    });
                },
```

Here is the php table which just is ordered by category_id

```
<div class="wpProQuiz_catOverview" <?php $this->isDisplayNone($this->quiz->isShowCategoryScore()); ?>>
                    <h4><?php _e('Categories', 'wp-pro-quiz'); ?></h4>
                    <div style="margin-top: 10px;">
                        <ol>
                            <?php foreach($this->category as $cat) {
                                if(!$cat->getCategoryId()) {
                                    $cat->setCategoryName(__('Not categorized', 'wp-pro-quiz'));
                                }
                            ?>
                            <li data-category_id="<?php echo $cat->getCategoryId();?>">
                                <span class="wpProQuiz_catName"><?php echo $cat->getCategoryName(); ?></span>
                                <span class="wpProQuiz_catPercent">0%</span>
                            </li>
                            <?php } ?>
                        </ol>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: Are you generating the data coming out of the database? If so you should sort there.

Comment: @JayBlanchard - categories are stored in one table and question answers are in another table.  The category results are derived from joining the question_answer table to category table so that each question is assigned a category.  That is where the catResults and CatPoints (max points) come from.

Answer (score 0):

As JayBlanchard is proposing, the best option would be to generate the percentages and do the ordering beforehand (in the server side). However, it might be possible that that isn't an option. You could try this approach to do the ordenation in the client side ([**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/djdrcfzf/2/)):

```
// Pre-calculate the percentages using js as you're doing.
var results = [];
$("ol li").each(function (index, item) {// Store the results in an array of objects.
    results.push({
        id: $(item).data("category_id"),
        name: $(".wpProQuiz_catName", this).text(),
        percentage: $(".wpProQuiz_catPercent",this).text()
    });
});

results.sort(function(a,b){// Sort the array by percentage.
    var numA = +(a.percentage.slice(0,-1)), numB = +(b.percentage.slice(0,-1));
    return numB - numA;// Ascending order
});

$("ol li").each(function (index, item) {// Substitute li information acccording to the ordered array.
    $(item).attr("data-category_id", results[index].id);
    $(".wpProQuiz_catName", this).text(results[index].name);
    $(".wpProQuiz_catPercent",this).text(results[index].percentage);
});
```

It can probably be done with less loops due to the fact that you're calculating the percentages somewhere else in your js (you could take advantage of that and create the array of results there).

Hope it helps.